# can i use variable as my index value in javascript for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```js
var tablNum = prompt("enter numberr");
var tableCout = (tablNum * 10) + 1 ;

for (let i = tablNum; i < tableCout; i = i + 10) {
    console.log(i)
    
}
```

This is my code but when I run my code, the loop works. I am trying to make math table generator this is my code but its not working.

```js
var tablNum = prompt("enter number");
var tableCout = (tablNum * 10) + 1 ;

for (let i = tablNum; i < tableCout; i = i + 10) {
    console.log(i)
    
}
```

And what I want from my code to do is generate a table which number I type.

Comment: What is the difference between the two snippets? Unclear what the question is.

Comment: You should specify what isn't working, what you have tried and what you want to achieve

Comment: If you get a error please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting if, for example, you enter `3`? Is it meant to be a ["3 times table"](https://www.timestables.com/3-times-table.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert what you get from prompt from a string to a number.

```
var tablNum = Number(prompt("enter number"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're after creating "times tables" you may find this example useful.

1. `prompt` will always return a string so to use that in your loop you'll need to coerce it to an integer either by using the [`Number` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) or by prefixing a `+` to the prompt.
2. "times tables" are generally multiples of 12 so we shall use that value in the calculation.
3. The loop needs to go from `n` (the number from the prompt) up to the bound of `n * 12`, and increasing by `n` on each iteration:

   ```
   for (let i = n; i <= bound; i += n) {
   ```
4. If you want a table it might be best use the features available to you as a developer. Here I've created a grid using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) which allows you specify how many columns/rows you want. I've specified four columns 30 pixels wide: `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 30px)`.

   Then, in your loop, create some elements (I've given them a class name of `box`). Here I've created a [fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) first to which the elements are added. Once the iteration is complete the fragment is added to the page.

```js
// Coerce the prompt (a string) to an integer
const n = Number(prompt('Enter a number'));

// Set the upper bound for the loop
const bound = n * 12;

// Cache the grid element, and create a
// document fragment
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Loop from `n` to the upperbound increase by n
// on each iteration
for (let i = n; i <= bound; i += n) {

  // Create an element, add a `box` style to it
  // set its text content, and then add it
  // to the fragment
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.className = 'box';
  box.textContent = i;
  frag.appendChild(box);
}

// Finally add the fragment to the grid
grid.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
:root { --grid-width: 4; }
.grid { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 30px); gap: 0.5em; width: 50%;}
.box { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; border: 1px solid lightgray; width: 30px; height: 30px; font-size: 0.9em; border-radius: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `tablNum` contains the inputted value by the user as a string, but you are treating it as a number, as a result it is sometimes coerced to a number and other times it is not, for example `i = i + 10` will treat the `i` as a string and concatenate "10" with the `i`, while comparison will treat it as a number.

You must explicitly set the type of that `tablNum` variable to be number, you can use the `parseInt()` or `Number()` functions to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a multipilication table I think this code will help you:

```
const number = parseInt(prompt('Enter an integer: '));

//creating a multiplication table
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    // multiply i with number
    const result = i * number;

    // display the result
    console.log(`${number} * ${i} = ${result}`);
}
```